# Rotated plane—projected and drawn in 2D—looks crooked instead of straight at some edges

Tags: vb.net, geometry, drawing, formula, projection

**Introductory remarks**

The purpose of this program is to rotate a [mathematical plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)) around the x and z axes and to project this onto the 2D GUI.
First about the sign convention:
The plane lies in the xz-plane (so at the origin), where +x goes to the right, +y to the depth of the picture and +z to the top (compare: I look at another person as a person).

Many vectors are used to fill the surface. Depending on the size of the plane, there are often more than 40,000 vectors. So I decided to run the calculation function asynchronously. Since it is now cumbersome / nonsensical to paint in the PictureBox, I write in a bitmap, which I then assign to the PictureBox after each calculation process. Since the `Graphics.DrawLine` function reached its limits in terms of performance, I integrated `SkiaSharp` from Visual Studio's own Nuget package manager. Now, I write in an SKBtmap and can move the plane with the WASD keys and get a new image within a few hundred milliseconds.

For the projection, I use a formula that I found at StackOverflow a few months ago. I have now shown it clearly and distinctly. Since the plane partly comes towards me when turning, the distance to me changes. So, I subtract the `distance_to_plane` to get the real distance.

```
Dim projected As New PointF(
                            CSng((Camera - Window_distance) / (Camera - distance_to_plane) * rotatedVec.X),
                            CSng(-(Camera - Window_distance) / (Camera - distance_to_plane) * rotatedVec.Z))
```

**What is my concern to you:**

As you can see from the pictures, the plane has some curves (outliers) at the edges where it should be straight instead. I can't explain the effect.
I suspect the above formula. To remedy this, I set the camera very far away from the plane, and the projection window far away ‘enough’ from both the camera and the plane.
I'll put the complete source code online, maybe it's something else (a typical effect?).

Form ‘Create’ to instantiate a new plane.
[image: Form ‘Create’ to instantiate a new plane]

Plane strongly rotated around the z-axis with odd edges in the middle. As you can see from the values, the camera is currently 2660 units of length away from the plane, and the projection window is 1000 units of length. (Camera – window 1660)
[image: rotated plane no. 1]

[image: rotated plane no. 2]

**Form1.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Plane1 As PlaneInTermsOfGeometry = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")

    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(184, 176, 143)
        For Each but As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
            but.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(201, 200, 193)
        Next
        TextBox_Window.Text = "-1000"
        Label5.Text = ""
        Label6.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormMain_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        New_Plane()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_new_plane_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_new_plane.Click
        New_Plane()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub New_Plane()
        Using FNP As New FormCreateNewPlane
            If FNP.ShowDialog(Me) <> DialogResult.OK Then
                Return
            End If
            Plane1 = New PlaneInTermsOfGeometry(
                FNP.A0x,
                FNP.A0y,
                FNP.A0z,
                FNP.ABx,
                FNP.ABy,
                FNP.ABz,
                FNP.ACx,
                FNP.ACy,
                FNP.ACz,
                FNP.Enlargement)
            Await Plane1.process_async()
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
            Label5.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_x_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
            Label6.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_z_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
            TextBox_Kamera.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.Camera, 0).ToString(Deu)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_Kamera_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_Kamera.TextChanged
        If Plane1 Is Nothing Then Return

        Dim Kamera As Double
        If Double.TryParse(TextBox_Kamera.Text, Kamera) Then
            TextBox_Kamera.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
            Plane1.Camera = Kamera
        Else
            TextBox_Kamera.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_Fenster_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_Window.TextChanged
        If Plane1 Is Nothing Then Return

        Dim Fenster As Double
        If Double.TryParse(TextBox_Window.Text, Fenster) Then
            TextBox_Window.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
            Plane1.Window_distance = Fenster
        Else
            TextBox_Window.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub FormMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If Plane1 Is Nothing Then Return

        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.W
                If Plane1.current_x_angle > -90.0 Then
                    Plane1.change_x_angle(-1.0)
                    Await Plane1.process_async()
                    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                    GC.Collect()
                    PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
                    Label5.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_x_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    Label6.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_z_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    TextBox_KOForm.Text = Plane1.Cartesian_Equation()
                End If
            Case Keys.S
                If Plane1.current_x_angle < 90.0 Then
                    Plane1.change_x_angle(1.0)
                    Await Plane1.process_async()
                    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                    GC.Collect()
                    PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
                    Label5.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_x_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    Label6.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_z_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    TextBox_KOForm.Text = Plane1.Cartesian_Equation()
                End If
            Case Keys.A
                If Plane1.current_z_angle > -90.0 Then
                    Plane1.change_z_angle(-1.0)
                    Await Plane1.process_async()
                    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                    GC.Collect()
                    PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
                    Label5.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_x_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    Label6.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_z_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    TextBox_KOForm.Text = Plane1.Cartesian_Equation()
                End If
            Case Keys.D
                If Plane1.current_z_angle < 90.0 Then
                    Plane1.change_z_angle(1.0)
                    Await Plane1.process_async()
                    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                    GC.Collect()
                    PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
                    Label5.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_x_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    Label6.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.current_z_angle, 0).ToString(Deu)
                    TextBox_KOForm.Text = Plane1.Cartesian_Equation()
                End If
            Case Else
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub FormMain_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
        If Plane1 Is Nothing Then Return

        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            ' The Camera must be in front of the window.
            If (Plane1.Camera - Plane1.Window_distance) < 0.0 Then
                Plane1.change_Camera_distance(20.0)
                Await Plane1.process_async()
                PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                GC.Collect()
                PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
            End If
        Else
            Plane1.change_Camera_distance(-20.0)
            Await Plane1.process_async()
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            GC.Collect()
            PictureBox1.Image = PlaneInTermsOfGeometry.displayedBitmap
        End If

        TextBox_Kamera.Text = Math.Round(Plane1.Camera, 0).ToString(Deu)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**class PlaneInTermsOfGeometry** (By the way: I was politely instructed to choose a reasonable name for this class instead of just "Plane"...)

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Media3D
Imports SkiaSharp
Public NotInheritable Class PlaneInTermsOfGeometry
    Private Structure VA0
        Public x As Double
        Public y As Double
        Public z As Double
    End Structure
    Private A0 As VA0

    Private Structure VAB
        Public x As Double
        Public y As Double
        Public z As Double
    End Structure
    '       →
    Private AB As VAB

    Private Structure VAC
        Public x As Double
        Public y As Double
        Public z As Double
    End Structure
    '       →
    Private AC As VAC

    Private ReadOnly allVectors As New List(Of Vector3D)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' in degrees
    ''' </summary>
    Public current_x_angle As Double = 0.0
    ''' <summary>
    ''' in degrees
    ''' </summary>
    Public current_z_angle As Double = 0.0
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The picture in which is written and which is shown by the PictureBox. 
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared displayedBitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The camera position on the y-axis (we look along the +y arrow). 
    ''' </summary>
    Public Camera As Double = -2660.0
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The projection window position on the y-axis. Absolute value!
    ''' </summary>
    Public Window_distance As Double = -1000.0
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The distance from the origin of coordinates to the x-length 
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly oneSide As Double

    Private ReadOnly Grid As New List(Of Vector3D)

    Public Sub New(ByVal A0x As Double,
                   ByVal A0y As Double,
                   ByVal A0z As Double,
                   ByVal ABx As Double,
                   ByVal ABy As Double,
                   ByVal ABz As Double,
                   ByVal ACx As Double,
                   ByVal ACy As Double,
                   ByVal ACz As Double,
                   ByVal enlarg As Double)
        Me.A0.x = A0x
        Me.A0.y = A0y
        Me.A0.z = A0z
        Me.AB.x = ABx * enlarg
        Me.AB.y = ABy
        Me.AB.z = ABz
        Me.AC.x = ACx
        Me.AC.y = ACy
        Me.AC.z = ACz * enlarg
        Me.oneSide = ABx * enlarg

        For x As Double = -AB.x To AB.x Step 1.0
            For z As Double = -AC.z To AC.z Step 2.0
                allVectors.Add(New Vector3D(x, 0.0, z))
                ' For the grid
                If CSng(x) Mod 15.0F = 0.0F Then
                    Grid.Add(New Vector3D(x, 0.0, z))
                Else
                    Grid.Add(New Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub change_Camera_distance(ByVal dy As Double)
        Camera += dy
    End Sub

    Public Sub change_x_angle(ByVal value As Double)
        current_x_angle += value
    End Sub

    Public Sub change_z_angle(ByVal value As Double)
        current_z_angle += value
    End Sub

    Private Function rotate_around_x_axis(ByVal vec1 As Vector3D) As Vector3D
        Return New Vector3D(
            vec1.X,
            vec1.Y * Math.Cos(current_x_angle * Math.PI / 180.0) - vec1.Z * Math.Sin(current_x_angle * Math.PI / 180.0),
            vec1.Y * Math.Sin(current_x_angle * Math.PI / 180.0) + Math.Cos(current_x_angle * Math.PI / 180.0) * vec1.Z)
    End Function

    Private Function rotate_around_z_axis(ByVal vec2 As Vector3D) As Vector3D
        Return New Vector3D(
            Math.Cos(current_z_angle * Math.PI / 180.0) * vec2.X - vec2.Y * Math.Sin(current_z_angle * Math.PI / 180.0),
            Math.Sin(current_z_angle * Math.PI / 180.0) * vec2.X + vec2.Y * Math.Cos(current_z_angle * Math.PI / 180.0),
            vec2.Z)
    End Function

    Public Async Function process_async() As Task(Of Boolean)
        Return Await Task.Run(Function() processing())
    End Function

    Private Function processing() As Boolean
        displayedBitmap = Nothing

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim imageInfo As New SKImageInfo(FormMain.PictureBox1.Size.Width, FormMain.PictureBox1.Size.Height)
        Using surface As SKSurface = SKSurface.Create(imageInfo)
            Using canvas As SKCanvas = surface.Canvas
                canvas.Translate(FormMain.PictureBox1.Size.Width \ 2, FormMain.PictureBox1.Size.Height \ 2)

                Using DarkBlue As New SKPaint With {
                                .TextSize = 64.0F,
                                .IsAntialias = True,
                                .Color = New SKColor(0, 64, 255),
                                 .Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill
                                 }
                    Using BrightYellow As New SKPaint With {
                        .TextSize = 64.0F,
                        .IsAntialias = True,
                        .Color = New SKColor(255, 255, 64),
                        .Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill
                        }

                        For Each vec As Vector3D In allVectors
                            Dim rotatedVec As Vector3D = rotate_around_z_axis(rotate_around_x_axis(vec))

                            If rotatedVec.Y > Window_distance Then ' The object is not further back than the window (the window is not in the object). When false, don't draw!
                                Dim Angle_in_degrees As Double = Vector3D.AngleBetween(
                                    rotatedVec,
                                    New Vector3D(rotatedVec.X, 0.0, rotatedVec.Z))

                                If Double.IsNaN(Angle_in_degrees) Then
                                    i += 1
                                    Continue For
                                End If

                                ' Opposite cathetus
                                Dim distance_to_plane As Double = oneSide * Math.Sin(Angle_in_degrees * Math.PI / 180.0)
                                Dim projected As New PointF(
                                        CSng((Camera - Window_distance) / (Camera - distance_to_plane) * rotatedVec.X),
                                        CSng(-(Camera - Window_distance) / (Camera - distance_to_plane) * rotatedVec.Z))

                                If Grid(i).X = 0.0 AndAlso Grid(i).Y = 0.0 AndAlso Grid(i).Z = 0.0 Then
                                    ' draw the mathematical plane
                                    canvas.DrawPoint(projected.X, projected.Y, DarkBlue)
                                Else
                                    ' draw the grid (Gitternetz)
                                    canvas.DrawPoint(projected.X, projected.Y, BrightYellow)
                                End If

                                i += 1
                            End If
                        Next
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
            ' get the data into ‘displayedBitmap’ because the PictureBox is only accepting an usual System.Drawing.Bitmap.
            '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

            Using image As SKImage = surface.Snapshot()
                Using data As SKData = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100)
                    Using mStream As New IO.MemoryStream(data.ToArray())
                        displayedBitmap = New Bitmap(mStream, False)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

        End Using
        Return True
    End Function

    'Koordinatenform
    Public Function Cartesian_Equation() As String
        Dim _N As Vector3D = Vector3D.CrossProduct(rotate_around_z_axis(New Vector3D(AB.x, AB.y, AB.z)), rotate_around_x_axis(New Vector3D(AC.x, AC.y, AC.z)))

        Dim _xMinusA0 As String
        Dim _yMinusA0 As String
        Dim _zMinusA0 As String

        If A0.x = 0.0 Then
            _xMinusA0 = "x"
        Else
            _xMinusA0 = $"(x - {A0.x.ToString(FormMain.Deu)})"
        End If
        If A0.y = 0.0 Then
            _yMinusA0 = "y"
        Else
            _yMinusA0 = $"(y - {A0.y.ToString(FormMain.Deu)})"
        End If
        If A0.z = 0.0 Then
            _zMinusA0 = "z"
        Else
            _zMinusA0 = $"(z - {A0.z.ToString(FormMain.Deu)})"
        End If

        Return ($"{Math.Round(_N.X, 3).ToString(FormMain.Deu)} * {_xMinusA0} + {Math.Round(_N.Y, 3).ToString(FormMain.Deu)} * {_yMinusA0} + {Math.Round(_N.Z, 3).ToString(FormMain.Deu)} * {_zMinusA0}").ToString(FormMain.Deu)
    End Function
End Class
```

For the sake of completeness, if someone wants to recreate it, here is FormNewPlane.vb to create a new plane, as shown in the first picture.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars
Public NotInheritable Class FormCreateNewPlane
    Public A0x, A0y, A0z, ABx, ABy, ABz, ACx, ACy, ACz, Enlargement As Double

    Private Sub FormCreateNewPlane_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(184, 176, 143)
        For Each but As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
            but.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(201, 200, 193)
        Next

        If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\Preview.png") Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Preview.png")
        End If

        'Since this is a plane that lies in the xz plane, only the text box contents that display a 1 should be changed.
        Label5.Text = $"Da es hier um eine Ebene geht, die{NewLine}in der xz-Ebene liegt, sollen nur die{NewLine}Textbox-Inhalte verändert werden,{NewLine}die eine 1 anzeigen."
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormCreateNewPlane_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonOK.Click
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxA0x_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxA0x.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxA0x.Text, A0x) Then
            TextBoxA0x.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxA0x.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxA0y_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxA0y.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxA0y.Text, A0y) Then
            TextBoxA0y.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxA0y.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxA0z_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxA0z.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxA0z.Text, A0z) Then
            TextBoxA0z.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxA0z.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxABx_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxABx.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxABx.Text, ABx) Then
            TextBoxABx.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxABx.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxABy_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxABy.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxABy.Text, ABy) Then
            TextBoxABy.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxABy.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxABz_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxABz.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxABz.Text, ABz) Then
            TextBoxABz.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxABz.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxACx_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxACx.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxACx.Text, ACx) Then
            TextBoxACx.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxACx.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxACy_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxACy.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxACy.Text, ACy) Then
            TextBoxACy.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxACy.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxACz_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxACz.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBoxACz.Text, ACz) Then
            TextBoxACz.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBoxACz.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_Enlarg_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_Enlarg.TextChanged
        If Double.TryParse(TextBox_Enlarg.Text, Enlargement) Then
            TextBox_Enlarg.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
        Else
            TextBox_Enlarg.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_Enlarg_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox_Enlarg.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If Double.TryParse(TextBox_Enlarg.Text, Enlargement) Then
                TextBox_Enlarg.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 125, 0)
            Else
                TextBox_Enlarg.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If

            Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_Enlarg_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox_Enlarg.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(13) Then e.Handled = True ' This suppresses the ‘ding’ sound.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to apply `perspective projection` to the points, the `projected` point should be something like this;

```
Dim projected As New PointF(
    CSng((Camera - Window_distance) / (Camera - rotatedVec.Y) * rotatedVec.X),
    CSng(-(Camera - Window_distance) / (Camera - rotatedVec.Y) * rotatedVec.Z))

' In short, distance_to_plane = rotatedVec.Y
```